# Исходный код для android

Tags: android, java, android-studio

Где можно взять исходный код, который можно будет указать в android studio? чтобы рассматривать код из studio, сейчас он показывает скомпилированный код и кнопку Attach resource.

Comment: @eldqs, Оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы хоть раз открывали Android SDK Manager?
[image]
Такое есть для каждой версии Android.